# Token with Oauth2 in Google Apps

Tags: token

I want to connect to Resource calendar API with Oauth2 but the token given expire in 3600sec, how can i have an unexpired token ?

I see information about offline token but i don't know how to use them ?
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer?hl=FR#offline

This is my script actually :

```
function doGet(e){

   if(e.parameter.code){
     var oauthResponse = getAndStoreAccessToken(e.parameter.code);
    PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("ResourceCalToken", oauthResponse);
    }
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('install').evaluate();
    }

   function getResourceCals(){
   var token = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("ResourceCalToken"));
   var url = 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/calendar/resource/2.0/'+ yourDomainName +'/'+             idresource +'';
   var parameters = { method : 'get',
                      headers : {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token.access_token},
                      contentType:'application/json',                   
                      muteHttpExceptions:true};
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,parameters).getContentText();



    Logger.log(response);


   }



  function getURLForAuthorization(){

    return AUTHORIZE_URL + '?response_type=code&client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&redirect_uri='+REDIRECT_URL +'&scope='+ scope;  
  }


  function getAndStoreAccessToken(code){
    var parameters = { method : 'post',
                      payload :       'client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET+'&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=' +REDIRECT_URL+'&code=' + code};
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(TOKEN_URL,parameters).getContentText();
  }
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To get a token that won't expire, you have to set your *access_type* to *offline*. Doing so will grant you a *refresh token* along with your access token. The refresh token will not expire, but you will have to make sure you store it properly, else you will have to go through the authorization process again. Google has Client Libraries in several different languages that help make the process much simpler. [Here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication)  is the one for JavaScript.

Hope that helps!